# True that $|gHg^{-1}|=|H|$?

Tags: group-theory

Stupid question, but suppose $H \subset G$ are groups, $g \in G$. Is it true that $|gHg^{-1}|=|H|$?

Suppose $H=\{ h_1,...,h_n \}$. Then $gH = \{ gh_1,...,gh_n \}$, and $gHg^{-1}= \{ gh_1 g^{-1},...,gh_n g^{-1} \}$. As far as I'm concerned that's an affirmative answer to my question, but perhaps I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true in general, even for infinite groups. In fact, for a given $g \in G$, the maps
$$
H \to g H g^{-1}, \qquad h \mapsto g h  g^{-1}
$$
and 
$$
g H  g^{-1} \to H, \qquad x \mapsto g^{-1} x  g
$$
are one the inverse of the other.

---

Or to put it a little differently, for a given $g \in G$, the maps
$$
\varphi : G \to G, \qquad x \mapsto g x g^{-1}
$$
and 
$$
G \to G, \qquad x \mapsto g^{-1} x  g
$$
are one the inverse of the other, and thus bijective. Thus the restriction to $H$ of $\varphi$ is a bijection between $H$ and $\varphi(H) = g H g^{-1}$.

Comment: Andreas and @Peter Thank you, both your responses answered my question. I'll give the "accept" to Andreas who answered first, hope that's alright :)

Comment: @ErikVesterlund Err... I am not saying you should unaccept, but check that clock again! =) Anyways, I don't think you should accept based on "quickness", but rather what **you** found most useful.

Comment: @Peter Weird! Sorry man, but anyway you're no pauper so you're alright ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to show $$gh_ig^{-1}=gh_jh^{-1}\implies i=j$$

to finish off. Of course, this is the same as showing that the maps $x\mapsto gx$ and $x\mapsto xh$ are both bijections for any $g,h\in G$. In particular, as Andreas notes, this holds for any group $G$, not only finite groups.